# Probability in exam (Possibly binomially distributed)

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions

### Question

There are $6$ questions on an exam which in each of them has two options to choose from. Each correct answer will result in 1 point. The well prepared student has a probability of $90\%$ of getting a correct answer from each question. The lazy student who has not prepared for the exam will pick a choice randomly on each question. Approximately 2/3 of all students are well prepared.

**(a)** What is the probability that the well prepared student gets 3 points from the exam ?

**(b)** What is the probability that the randomly picked student receives 3 points from the exam ?

---

### Attempt to solve:

Now i would make assumption that this is binomially distributed. Binomial distribution would be defined as:

$$ Pr(k;n,p)=Pr(X=k)=\binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} $$

We mark well prepared students with random variable $X$

Parameters

$P$ = probability for getting a single question correct.

$n$ = number of total points from the exam.

$k$ = number of points actually recieved from the exam.

**(a)**

$P=0.9 \quad$ we know this because it was provided in the question.

$n=6 \quad$ 6 points is maximum from the whole exam.

$k=3 \quad$ we want probability for exactly 3 points from the exam.

$$Pr(X=3)=\binom{6}{3}0.9^3(1-0.9)^{6-3}$$

$$Pr(X=3) \approx 1.46 \%$$

**(b)**

We can mark lazy students with random variable $Y$

$$Pr(Y=3)=\binom{6}{3}0.5^3(1-0.5)^{6-3}$$
$$Pr(Y=3)\approx 31.25\% $$

Now that we have probabilities for both well prepared and lazy students scoring exactly 3 points. And we know that $\frac{2}{3}$ of all students are well prepared and $\frac{1}{3}$ are lazy. We don't know exactly how many well prepared and how many lazy students attend the exam but we do know the proportions of each group.

We can mark these proportions with:

$A=$ Well prepared student.

$B=$ Lazy student.

$$A=\frac{2}{3}, \quad B=\frac{1}{3}$$

Now approximately

$A*0.0146 \approx $ number of well prepared students scoring exactly 3 points from the exam.

$B*0.3125 \approx $ number of lazy students scoring exactly 3 points from the exam.

In our case the result will be proportional since we don't know the actual size of these groups. Groups $A$ and $B$ don't have an intersection so in a sense they are independent of each other.

$$ Pr(X,Y=3 | x_i,y_i \in A+B)= (A(Pr(X=3)))+(B(Pr(Y=3)))$$
$$ Pr(X,Y=3 | x_i,y_i \in A+B)= (\frac{2}{3}*0.0146)+(\frac{1}{3}*0.3125)  $$
$$ Pr(X,Y=3 | x_i,y_i \in A+B)\approx 11.39\% $$

---

Now I would like to have some feedback on if my reasoning seems correct. If it isn't correct comment an alternative solution that would be highly appreciated. I have some degree of uncertainty on question **(b)** whether my solution is correct or not.

Thanks,

Tuki

Comment: One question at a time!

Comment: Your solutions look correct to me.